# Краш приложения при EditText.getText().ToString()

Tags: java, android

При попытке считать текст в Alert dialog с внешнего layout происходит краш.

Так выглядит activity для Allert dialog.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rString_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".add_rString">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loggin_text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Логин" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loggin_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loggin_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Пароль" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loggin_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Не думаю что есть особый смысл вставлять все части кода, поэтому оставим только проблемную часть, поскольку краш происходит на моменте getText();

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_rstring, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder password_check  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    AlertDialog pas_check = password_check.create();

    pas_check.setTitle("Введите текст");
    pas_check.setView(dialoglayout);

    pas_check.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String p_login = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.loggin_password)).getText().toString(); //Проблемное место
            String p_pasword = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.loggin_password)).getText().toString();
            if (p_login  == "Admin" && p_pasword == "admin")
                {
                    Intent viewStart = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.dyplom.View.class);
                    startActivity(viewStart);
                    pas_check.cancel();
                }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Неправильный логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.loggin_password)).setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    pas_check.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            pas_check.cancel();
        }
    });
    pas_check.show();
```

Вывод консоли

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dyplom, PID: 10508
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dyplom.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Почему может происходить краш?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему приведённый вами код написан в активити и, засим, вызывая метод findViewById в слушателе нажатий кнопки диалога вы вызываете метод активити, который пытается вьюху искать в разметке оной, а не в разметке диалога. Получается в итоге null и закономерный NPE.

Следовательно, надо заменить findViewById на

> dialoglayout.findViewById

Comment: Благодарю, сколько пытался найти в интернете нормальную работу AlertDialog, так ничего и не нашел. Либо я просто не умею икать)

Comment: Вы просто не учли нюанс, что в активити код писать не принято) Обычно вечь код во фрагментах и там у вас бы не произошло такой проблемы - компилятор бы сказал, что метода findViewById - нет)

Comment: Ну, я только начинаю изучать как саму Java(более углубленно, а не поверхностно как это было на парах), так и Android studio. Век живи - век учись)